# Tables equates?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there any way if I can equate these two table,

```
h = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 1}]
p = Table[j, {j, 0, 255, 51}]
```

now how can I equate these two tables, let's say 0 of h corresponds to 0 of p and 1 of h corressponds to
51 of p and so on.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Probably I'm just dumb, but I'm not sure how someone is supposed to guess what you're looking for from your very short question. Given `h` and `p` as above, what should the output be? Are you just comparing the final digit? If so, does this work: `(Last[IntegerDigits[#]] & /@ h) == (Last[IntegerDigits[#]] & /@ p)`?

Comment: @MassDefect I can access the 4th element of the h[[4]], is there any way around it, I mean the 3 is the 4th element of h.

Comment: Do you want to pair the elements? You can do this by: Transpose[{h,p}]

Comment: How about p[[(h[[n]] 50)+51]]?

Comment: let t = Thread[{h, p}]. Then the first element of t, t[[1]] is the pair {0,0} which are the first h and p values, t[[2]] is {1,51} which is the second h, p values, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since both of them are an arithmetic sequence (a sequence with equal step size) you can use `Differences`:

```
h = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 1}];
p = Table[j, {j, 0, 255, 51}];
```

If you apply once, you'll get step size:

```
Differences[h]
(* Out: {1,1,1,1,1} *)

Differences[p]
(* Out: {51,51,51,51,51} *)
```

Now you can use various ways to equate them, here we'll use another `Differences`:

```
Differences[Differences[h]]
(* Out: {0,0,0,0} *)

Differences[Differences[p]]
(* Out: {0,0,0,0} *)
```

Simplified solution (use `Nest` to apply `Differences` 2 times):

```
Nest[Differences, p, 2] == Nest[Differences, h, 2]

(* Out: True *)
```